# Nativescript Angular2: Get Listview label Index or Text on Tap

Tags: android, listview, angular2-nativescript

Angular2 Nativescript Android:
I have a listview populated with labels from a 1xN array of strings.  When the user taps one of the labels in the listview, I would like to set a variable equal to either the index of that label or the label's text.

How should I modify my xml and/or selectPlan() to do this?

```
    <ListView [items]="submenu">
        <template let-item="item">
            <Label [text]="item" class="subUnselected" (tap)="selectPlan()"></Label>
        </template>
    </ListView>
```

Here is what worked:

```
<ListView [items]="submenu">
    <template let-item="item">
        <Label [text]="item" class="subUnselected" (tap)="selectPlan(item)"></Label>
    </template>
</ListView>


selectPlan(item) {
    var plan = item;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass it to `selectPlan()`, so it becomes `selectPlan(item)`.

Then adjust the function in your component accordingly.